# How can I fix my method "add" to cart to populate my shopping cart in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am trying to currently create a simple shopping cart  which will be saved in the session but so far not working for me.
Returning Error: No route matches [GET] "/cart/2"

Here s my add from my cart controller

```
  def index
    session[:cart] = {}
    render 'cart/index'
  end

def add
    @catalogue = Catalogue.find(params[:id])
    cart = session[:cart]
    cart = {:id => Catalogue.find(params[:id]) , :catalogue => @catalogue.name,category => @catalogue.category, :code => @catalogue.code , :colour=> @catalogue.colour, :description => @catalogue.description, :image  => @catalogue.image , :unitprice => @catalogue.unitprice, :unitquantity => += @catalogue.unitquantity, :unitweight => @catalogue.unitweight }
    session[:cart] = cart
    render 'cart/add'
    end`
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here s my rake routes... 
rake routes

```
               cart_index GET    /cart/index(.:format)           cart#index
             cart_success GET    /cart/success(.:format)         cart#success
                          PUT    /cart/:id(.:format)             cart#add
                          DELETE /cart/:id(.:format)             cart#remove
                     cart DELETE /cart(.:format)                 cart#clear
            cart_checkout POST   /cart/checkout(.:format)        cart#checkout
        new_admin_session GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions
#new
            admin_session POST   /admins/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions
#create
    destroy_admin_session DELETE /admins/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions
#destroy
           admin_password POST   /admins/password(.:format)      devise/password
s#create
       new_admin_password GET    /admins/password/new(.:format)  devise/password
s#new
      edit_admin_password GET    /admins/password/edit(.:format) devise/password
s#edit
                          PUT    /admins/password(.:format)      devise/password
s#update
cancel_admin_registration GET    /admins/cancel(.:format)        devise/registra
tions#cancel
       admin_registration POST   /admins(.:format)               devise/registra
tions#create
   new_admin_registration GET    /admins/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registra
tions#new
  edit_admin_registration GET    /admins/edit(.:format)          devise/registra
tions#edit
                          PUT    /admins(.:format)               devise/registra
tions#update
                          DELETE /admins(.:format)               devise/registra
tions#destroy
               catalogues GET    /catalogues(.:format)           catalogues#inde
x
                          POST   /catalogues(.:format)           catalogues#crea
te
            new_catalogue GET    /catalogues/new(.:format)       catalogues#new
           edit_catalogue GET    /catalogues/:id/edit(.:format)  catalogues#edit

                catalogue GET    /catalogues/:id(.:format)       catalogues#show

                          PUT    /catalogues/:id(.:format)       catalogues#upda
te
                          DELETE /catalogues/:id(.:format)       catalogues#dest
roy
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions
#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions
#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions
#destroy
            user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/password
s#create
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/password
s#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/password
s#edit
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/password
s#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registra
tions#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                devise/registra
tions#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registra
tions#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registra
tions#edit
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                devise/registra
tions#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                devise/registra
tions#destroy
```

And finally my add to cart button

```
<%= link_to "Add to cart", controller: "cart", action: "add", id: catalogue.id , method: :post %>
```

Edit:

I have change my link to add an item to my cart from the above to

```
<td><%= link_to "Add to cart", add_cart_path(catalogue.id), method: :get %></td>
or 
<td><%= link_to "Add to cart", add_cart_path(catalogue.id), method: :get %></td>
```

and now getting the following error:

```
undefined method `add_cart_path' for #<#<Class:0x5e4f070>:0x400cd40>

Extracted source (around line #36):

33:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', catalogue %></td>
34:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_catalogue_path(catalogue) %></td>
35:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', catalogue, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
36:     <td><%= link_to "Add to cart", add_cart_path(catalogue.id), method: :post %></td>
37:     
38:   </tr>
39: <% end %>

Rails.root: C:/Users/Vincent/Desktop/BSHCE4/sewingsupplies - 22-03
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/catalogues/index.html.erb:36:in `block in _app_views_catalogues_index_html_erb__837547684_33595272'
app/views/catalogues/index.html.erb:21:in `each'
app/views/catalogues/index.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_catalogues_index_html_erb__837547684_33595272'
app/controllers/catalogues_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Still not working for me.

Edit:

routes.rb

```
Sewingsupplies::Application.routes.draw do
  # get "cart/index"

  # get "cart/success"

  # put "/cart/:id" => "cart#add"
  # delete "/cart/:id" => "cart#remove"
  # delete "/cart" => "cart#clear"
  # post "/cart/checkout"

  resources :carts do
  member do
    put 'add'
  end
end

  devise_for :admins

  resources :catalogues


  devise_for :users
```

Rake routes:

```
    cart_index GET    /cart/index(.:format)           cart#index
             cart_success GET    /cart/success(.:format)         cart#success
                          PUT    /cart/:id(.:format)             cart#add
                          DELETE /cart/:id(.:format)             cart#remove
                     cart DELETE /cart(.:format)                 cart#clear
            cart_checkout POST   /cart/checkout(.:format)        cart#checkout
        new_admin_session GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions
#new
            admin_session POST   /admins/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions
#create
    destroy_admin_session DELETE /admins/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions
#destroy
           admin_password POST   /admins/password(.:format)      devise/password
s#create
       new_admin_password GET    /admins/password/new(.:format)  devise/password
s#new
      edit_admin_password GET    /admins/password/edit(.:format) devise/password
s#edit
                          PUT    /admins/password(.:format)      devise/password
s#update
cancel_admin_registration GET    /admins/cancel(.:format)        devise/registra
tions#cancel
       admin_registration POST   /admins(.:format)               devise/registra
tions#create
   new_admin_registration GET    /admins/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registra
tions#new
  edit_admin_registration GET    /admins/edit(.:format)          devise/registra
tions#edit
                          PUT    /admins(.:format)               devise/registra
tions#update
                          DELETE /admins(.:format)               devise/registra
tions#destroy
               catalogues GET    /catalogues(.:format)           catalogues#inde
x
                          POST   /catalogues(.:format)           catalogues#crea
te
            new_catalogue GET    /catalogues/new(.:format)       catalogues#new
           edit_catalogue GET    /catalogues/:id/edit(.:format)  catalogues#edit

                catalogue GET    /catalogues/:id(.:format)       catalogues#show

                          PUT    /catalogues/:id(.:format)       catalogues#upda
te
                          DELETE /catalogues/:id(.:format)       catalogues#dest
roy
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions
#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions
#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions
#destroy
            user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/password
s#create
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/password
s#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/password
s#edit
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/password
s#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registra
tions#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                devise/registra
tions#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registra
tions#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registra
tions#edit
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                devise/registra
tions#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                devise/registra
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust `routes.rb` file accordingly

Comment: Here s the route line in charge of the add to cart 


put "/cart/:id" => "cart#add"

Still not working for me

Comment: Can you copy the whole "block" from this file ? It is hard to say anything by looking at this line.

Also, `rake routes | grep "cart"` command would be very useful just for checking out, what routes are in use.

Comment: It seems fine but as you have asked... Here it is.

Comment: Well, in your original question you mention that "GET" is not working. And I see no problem, according to your `rake routes` output. It's not supposed to work. 

Maybe you defined cart as a singular object ? `resource :card`

BTW, your approach is really strange. Don't get me wrong, but cart is meant to be singular. And if you want to add a new item into it, you need to pass the ID of the item in the POST form, instead of link.

Comment: I am new to rails, started to learn it abt a month ago and was asked to develop a project with a shopping cart... Btw: how do I do to pass the ID of the item in the post form?

Comment: Well, for example by using `hidden field` with value of the item's ID.

And this form should be posted as a POST/PUT update action to your `cart` resource (but it should be a singular resource in this case), where it would get the product by its ID and does everything it needs. More about it, here -http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Alternatively, you could modify your products (catalogue) and include a new action with the name "add_to_cart".

So the link would look like this: /catalogues/2/add_to_cart
Where it would do the same shopping cart processing procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems from rake routes output, you don't have member method add for cart resource. Add it this way:

```
resources :cards do
  member do
    put 'add'
  end
end
```

Read about routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: I have tried your method and I am now getting the following error: 
No route matches {:controller=>"cart", :action=>"add", :id=>2, :method=>:post}

Comment: Now you need to look up rake routes and use add_cards_path (something like that) path helper function instead of controller/action notation.

Comment: how do i sort the error: 
undefined method `add_cart_path' for #<#<Class:0x5e4f070>:0x57f4d70>

Comment: please update your question with current state of code.

Comment: I have added more details to the problem like you have asked me.

Comment: Rake routes still old. Please provide routes.rb and rake routes output.

Comment: Find rake routes result and routes.rb file above